# MIPS asm equivalent of x86 dup

Tags: assembly, mips

How do i pre-allocate AND fill array with constant value?

For example, on x86 platform:

```
foo dd 10 dup(7)
```

assembler will create a static array of 10 32-bit ints with each equal to 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an assembler directive. 
You would have to tell us what assembler are you using to see if it provides an analogous directive.
In SPIM (also in MARS) you would have to use the .word directive n-times.
Something like:

```
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
.word 7
```

Also, check the [SPIM reference](http://www.scss.tcd.ie/~waldroj/itral/spim_ref.html#directives) to see other similar directives.

With GAS, you could also use the directives .rept and .end to repeat a block of data. Something like:

```
.rept 10
.word 7
.endr
```

Comment: i'll use whatever assembler that supports this directive!! lol GAS, or anything else thats out there. Expanding the declaration isnt useful for huge arrays.

Comment: @Saideira: I updated the answer with an idea of how to do it if you are using GAS